# Как получить соседние клетки в квадратной матрице с учётом краёв

Tags: python, python-3.x

> На квадратном клетчатом поле живут бактерии. Мы капаем из пипетки антибиотик в некоторые клетки, что убивает часть бактерий: каждая капля антибиотика убивает 8 бактерий в той клетке, куда она попала, и по 4 бактерии в восьми (или менее, если клетка находится с краю поля) соседних клетках. Выясните, сколько бактерий осталось.
>
> ## Формат ввода
>
> На первой строке вводится натуральное число n≥3 — размер квадратного поля из клеток, в котором живут бактерии.
>
> Далее следует n2 чисел на отдельных строках, которые описывают количество бактерий в каждой клетке ряд за рядом сверху вниз, внутри ряда слева направо.
>
> Далее следует натуральное число k — количество капель антибиотика.
>
> Далее следует k пар чисел на отдельных строках — координаты клеток, в которые попали капли; сначала следует номер столбца (столбцы нумеруются слева направо), затем номер ряда (ряды нумеруются сверху вниз). Координаты отсчитываются с нуля, т. е. принимают значения от 0 до n-1.
>
> ## Формат вывода
>
> Выводится количество бактерий, выживших в каждой клетке.
>
> ## Пример 1
>
> Ввод
>
> 3
>
> 10
>
> 10
>
> 9
>
> 10
>
> 10
>
> 10
>
> 10
>
> 10
>
> 10
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> ## Вывод
>
> 0 2 5
>
> 2 0 6
>
> 6 6 6

Я в питоне новичок и у меня возникла проблема с тем, чтобы вычесть 4 из клеток, находящихся вокруг главной клетки.

```
n = int(input())
virus = []
for _ in range(n):
    new = []
    for _ in range(n):
        new.append(int(input()))
    virus.append(new)
m = int(input())
for _ in range(m):
    col = int(input())
    row = int(input())
    if virus[row][col] < 8:
        virus[row][col] = 0
    else:
        virus[row][col] -= 8
```

Попытался сделать так:

```
n = int(input())
virus = [[int(input()) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
m = int(input())
for _ in range(m):
    col = int(input())
    row = int(input())
    test = virus[row][col]
    if virus[row][col] < 8:
        virus[row][col] = 0
    else:
        virus[row][col] -= 8
    if row - 1 >= 0 and col - 1 >= 0:
        virus[row - 1][col] -= 4
        virus[row + 1][col] -= 4
        virus[row][col - 1] -= 4
        virus[row][col + 1] -= 4  
        virus[row - 1][col + 1] -= 4
        virus[row - 1][col - 1] -= 4
        virus[row + 1][col - 1] -= 4
        virus[row + 1][col + 1] -= 4  
    elif row - 1 < 0 and col - 1 >= 0:
        virus[row + 1][col] -= 4
        virus[row][col - 1] -= 4
        virus[row][col + 1] -= 4  
        virus[row + 1][col - 1] -= 4
        virus[row + 1][col + 1] -= 4  
    elif row - 1 >= 0 and col - 1 < 0:
        virus[row][col] -= 4
        virus[row + 1][col] -= 4
        virus[row][col + 1] -= 4  
        virus[row][col + 1] -= 4
        virus[row + 1][col + 1] -= 4 
    elif row - 1 < 0 and col - 1 < 0:
        virus[row + 1][col] -= 4
        virus[row][col + 1] -= 4  
        virus[row + 1][col + 1] -= 4         
for i in range(n):
    for k in range(n):
        if virus[i][k] < 0:
            virus[i][k] = 0  
        print(virus[i][k], end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Во втором варианте кода вы проверяете, что координаты соседей не меньше ноля. Но надо ещё проверять, что координаты не больше максимальной координаты - ведь там тоже край.

Comment: Вообще, через if получается очень много писанины, нужно рассмотреть очень много вариантов. Лучше сделать функцию, которая принимает координату клетки, и возвращает список её соседей с учётом краёв поля.

Comment: Функции пока что не изучал.

Comment: Ну тогда через if, но с учётом обоих краёв

Comment: чот много ифов накидал) elif тут не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я набросал такое. Хотите - разбирайтесь как работают функции. Не хотите - пишите с портянкой из условий.

Но в любом случае функции нужно осваивать, и лучше это не откладывать.

```
n = int(input())
virus = []
for _ in range(n):
    new = []
    for _ in range(n):
        new.append(int(input()))
    virus.append(new)


def kill_neighbors(row, col, max_size):

    def get_neighbors(row, col, max_size):
        neighbors = [(row + dr, col + cr)
                     for dr in (-1, 0, +1)
                     for cr in (-1, 0, +1)]
        filtered = [n for n in neighbors
                    if 0 <= n[0] <= (max_size - 1)
                    and 0 <= n[1] <= (max_size - 1)]
        return filtered

    neighbors = get_neighbors(row, col, max_size)
    for n in neighbors:
        virus[n[0]][n[1]] = max(
                                virus[n[0]][n[1]] - 4,
                                0)

m = int(input())
for _ in range(m):
    col = int(input())
    row = int(input())
    if virus[row][col] < 8:
        virus[row][col] = 0
    else:
        virus[row][col] -= 8

    kill_neighbors(row, col, max_size=n)


for i in range(n):
    for k in range(n):
        if virus[i][k] < 0:
            virus[i][k] = 0
        print(virus[i][k], end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

вычесть 4 из соседних с (row,col) ячеек очень просто:

```
virus[row-1][col]-=4
virus[row+1][col]-=4
virus[row][col-1]-=4
virus[row][col+1]-=4
```

Comment: Я понимаю, но надо еще учесть, если клетка находится с краю, к примеру.

Comment: так добавь if`ы

Comment: Посмотри, пожалуйста, что можно сделать